# Domino Designer - Disable Javascript Validation?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, validation, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Is it possible to disable JS validation in Domino Designer 8.5.3?

I'm accessing a database design where some 3rd party JS libraries (for example the Bootstrap min JS lib: bootstrap.min.js) have been installed within `Code/Script Libraries` rather than in the `Resources/Files` section.

The problem that this creates is that the built in JS validator now displays lots of JS errors in the Problems window whenever I'm accessing this application. Not the biggest deal but it makes seeing actual errors/warnings a bit more difficult to find.

I've tried enabling project specific settings and disabling the various JS validators in the Validation section but none seem to have any effect.

I've seen people mention that it's possible to disable this validation in standalone Eclipse but I can't seem to get anything to work in Domino Designer.

Any thoughts welcome.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge - there's no way to disable the validations except to move the JS libraries to Resources / Files.

For CSS files not even that is enough to get out of the crappy editor "enhancements".

You need change the extension for the CSS file to something else.

Don't forget to add the proper "Web Properties / Mime Type".

Once you've skipped the "help" from Domino Designer you should see a nice performance improvement...